# How to read the text file line by line and save even numbering lines to **even.txt** and odd numbering lines to **odd.txt** in c#?

Tags: c#

How to read the text file line by line and save even numbering lines to **even.txt** and odd numbering lines to **odd.txt** in c# ?

```
StreamReader dr=new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Venkatesh\Desktop\sample.txt");
string ln=string.Empty;
int c = 0;
while (ln != null)
{
    c += 1; 
    if (c%2 == 0){
        StreamWriter even = new StreamWriter(@"C:\even.txt");
        even.WriteLine(ln);
    }
    else {
        StreamWriter odd = new StreamWriter(@"C:\odd.txt");
        odd.WriteLine(ln);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question/problem/anything?

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow ,,now just i'm edited the post. and look the question....plz give me a solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Post the code you had previously. We will take what you've tried so far and steer you in the right direction. The code you had previously looked to be close.

Comment: using System;
using System.IO;




           StreamReader dr=new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Venkatesh\Desktop\sample.txt");
           string ln=string.Empty;
           
           int c = 0;
           while (ln != null)
           {
  if(c%2==0)
    {
     StreamWriter even =new StreamWriter(@"C:\even.txt");
     even.WriteLine(ln);
    }
  else
    {
      StreamWriter odd =new StreamWriter(@"C:\odd.txt");
      odd.WriteLine(ln);

Comment: @Hank  i''ve copied all the code and paste in the comment ,but it is not shown as I expected..:-)     is there is any other way  or do u want me post as a question in new

Comment: Please post it in the OP (original post) or accept the edit i suggested based on your previously posted code.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is something like this:

```
string ln = string.Empty;
int c = 0;

using (StreamWriter odd = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\rdaniel\Desktop\odd.txt"))
using (StreamWriter even = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\rdaniel\Desktop\even.txt"))
using (StreamReader dr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\rdaniel\Desktop\example.txt"))
{
    while (ln != null)
    {
        ln = dr.ReadLine();
        c += 1;
        if (c % 2 == 0)
        {
            even.WriteLine(ln);
        }
        else
        {
            odd.WriteLine(ln);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to include the call to Dispose() at the end - in fact, it would be preferable if these were included inside "using" or "try/catch/finally" blocks.

Comment: Yeah I'm tweaking that part now. I noticed as soon as I posted haha

Comment: They should be instantiated with new StreamWriter(@"C:\even.txt", true) so that they append instead of overwriting

Comment: its not working @hank May I know what is exactly write there plz

Comment: @EJoshuaS Right again. Updated answer works on my side.

Comment: tnq u @Hank for consideration...:-)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of opening/closing the output files in the loop, You can do it something like this...

```
using (var odd = File.CreateText("odd.txt"))
using (var even = File.CreateText("even.txt"))
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
    {
        (count++ % 2 == 0 ? even : odd).WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanq u @EZI ,but just let me know                                                       count++ % 2 == 0 ? even : odd).WriteLine(line) works

Comment: @Venkatesh It is just a shortcut for what @Hank does in his answer (9 lines starting with `c += 1;`) See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx